# How to change the color of ctrl/command+hover variable/method/class in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, colors

In eclipse, a command+hovered(or ctrl+hovered on Win) variable/method/class is displayed as a link in dark blue. It's indistinguishable in a dark color scheme.

I tried:

- General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts->Active hyperlink text color
- General->Appearance->Colors and Fonts->Hyperlink text color
- General->Editors->Text Editors->Linked Mode->Current Range
- General->Editors->Text Editors->Linked Mode->Editable Range

, since their default colors like the dark blue. And They do not work.

Is it possible to change that color and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It in the `General` -> `Editors` -> `Text Editors` choose `Hyperlink` in the list on the right and uncheck `System Default` and select desired color.